# How to efficiently manage large amount data in Web apps

Tags: azure-sql-database, cosmos-db

I am developing an application that needs to store a large amount of product data and display it in a web app. The data is generated every day, and each product will have approximately 100 rows per day, resulting in a total of approximately 1 million rows for the entire application per day.

One item looks like following:

```
{
   "ProductId": "P-1",
   "ReportDate": "2023-12-12",
   "Type": "T-1",
   "Usage": 100
}
```

Requirements:

- store data from now back 3 years
- performance for the last 3 months must be very fast
- user can choose any date range from now to 3 years back, *i.e. 2023-12-01 - 2023-12-12 or 2020-12-12 - 2023-12-12.*

The data is displaying in the table. The table contains a list of products with pagination, set to a default of 50 but can be changed up to 100. Each product is expandable, revealing an inner table with the product's data.

**Now, the problem I am facing is** that one day has 100 rows per product. So, for one page with 50 items, I need to load 50 * 100 rows. However, the date range makes it more complicated because a longer range means more data is loaded. Essentially, the data is not loaded directly to the web app; it is aggregated in memory, and the web app still displays only 100 rows per product. Since the date range depends entirely on the user, I don't have aggregated data by date range combinations.

Main query looks like following:

```
SELECT ProductId, Type, SUM(Usage) FROM c WHERE c.ProductId = "P-1" AND c.ReportDate >= '2023-12-01' and c.ReportDate <= '2023-12-12' GROUP BY c.ProductId, c.Type
```

Now, I am exploring how to handle this. Where should I store it? Our application uses Azure SQL, and some data is stored in CosmosDB.

Initially, I considered storing the data in CosmosDB. However, the data has dependencies on Azure SQL, such as the product name. Since the name can change, and these changes must be reflected in the product's data, I don't think it's a good idea to store them together. Additionally, the data is filtered by permissions stored in Azure SQL. For these reasons, I am leaning towards using Azure SQL. The potential issue is the size of the data; the table will be approximately 750 GB for three years of data.

I am also considering storing the last 3 months of data in Azure SQL as 'hot data,' and storing all remaining data, including those 3 months, in a different storage, perhaps CosmosDB, as 'cold data.

Moreover, I am considering sharding, but I'm unsure if it's suitable when I need access to some common data.

Please, do you have any advice on how to approach this?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "*I am leaning towards using Azure SQL. The potential issue is the size of the data; the table will be approximately 750 GB for three years of data.*" - Size of data at rest should not be a factor, at least from a performance perspective, for the decision of which database system to use. They all perform roughly the same. "*performance for the last 3 months must be very fast*" - How many rows is 3 months of data?...How fast is "*very fast*"? You probably don't need to pull and cache all 3 months of data at a time, and instead only a few pages of data that you rotate as they click through.

Comment: How many rows is 3 months of data? - For one product, it's approximately 4500 rows. The data is aggregated, and the response to the UI displays just 100 rows.
How fast is "very fast - Within 10 seconds, it's a standard Web API request, and the UI is awaiting the response.
You probably don't need to pull and cache all 3 months of data at a time, and instead only a few pages of data that you rotate as they click through. - Unfortunately, I need to display all 100 rows, which represent an aggregation of 4500 rows (in the case when the date range is 3 months, but it could be for the entire year)

Comment: "*How many rows is 3 months of data? - For one product, it's approximately 4500 rows.*" - Is the web app displaying only 1 product at a time to the user? "*How fast is "very fast - Within 10 seconds*" - Cool, that's a very realistic and easy runtime to achieve with any mainstream database system. "*Unfortunately, I need to display all 100 rows, which represent an aggregation of 4500 rows*" - Why wouldn't you do that aggregation in the database server so your request is only bringing back the 100 results rows?

Comment: Is the web app displaying only 1 product at a time to the user? - No, the products are displayed in the table with pagination options of 20, 50 (default), 100. Initially, we load all the data on the page at once. Perhaps in a subsequent task, we'll focus on optimization, and the data for a product will be loaded after the user expands that specific product.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do that aggregation in the database server so your request is only bringing back the 100 results rows? - You're right. Of course, the data will be grouped on the storage side, but the storage still needs to process all 4500 rows (3 months of data) and aggregate them. I meant that I can't store pre-aggregated data. Do you think on-the-fly aggregation on the large table will have good performance?

Comment: "*but the storage still needs to process all 4500 rows (3 months of data) and aggregate them. I meant that I can't store pre-aggregated data. Do you think on-the-fly aggregation on the large table will have good performance?*" - 4,500 rows is an extremely tiny amount of data. A database system can aggregate that in a few milliseconds or less *usually*. Seems very conducive to your needs since you have a limit of 10 seconds (10,000 milliseconds).